# R - converting Character strings into date with only Year/Month

Tags: r, date, formatting, time-series

Goal: Plot a time series.

Problem: X-axis data is of course viewed as a character and I'm having trouble converting the character into a date.

```
new.df <- df %>%
group_by(Month, Year) %>%
summarise(n = n())

new.df <- new.df %>%
unite(Date, Month, Year, sep = "/") %>%
mutate(Total = cumsum(n))
```

So, I end up with a data frame looking like this:

```
Date     n     Group    Total
8/2010   1       1        1
9/2010   414     1       415
etc
```

I'm trying to convert the Date column into a Date format.  The column is a character class.  So, I tried doing

```
new.df$Date <- as.Date(New.Patients$Date, %m/%Y)
```

However, when I do that, it replaces the entire Date column into NA's.

I'm not sure if this is because my single-digit month dates do not have 0's in front or not.  I did the unite() function just because I thought it may make it easier, but it might not.

I originally created the Year/Month variable with the lubridate package but I wasn't sure I could incorporate that here.  Bonus points if someone can show me how.

I would appreciate any help or guidance.  I'm sure it's not that hard I am just having a major brain fart at the moment.

Comment: A date also needs a day. Maybe try `as.Date(paste("01", New.Patients$Date, sep="/"), "%d/%m/%Y")`. Or use `lubridate::parse_date_time("8/2010", "mY")`.

Comment: Yes. That did it. 

I saw that solution in a similar thread but I didn't understand what the paste part was actually fixing (nor did it work in my own version of trying to implement that). I didn't realize that dates need days..... so, by pasting the "01" we are basically just adding an artificial day, right?

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
library(zoo) # for yearmon

new.df$Date <- as.yearmon(New.Patients$Date, format="%m/%Y")
```

But if you really need it to be as.Date then I guess you have to define day (e.g. 01) as @lukeA has suggested in comment.

Answer (score 2):

My issue, as pointed out by lukeA in the comments, is that the as.Date function requires a day to be somewhere within the character string.

Therefore, just by pasting "01" (or I think virtually any other two-digit combination would work) to the front of each date fixed the issue.